# Java makes a connection with mysql in one class, but not a different one

Tags: java, android, mysql, database

Im practising by making an app that would update information in a database by request. The problem is that I created methods in `main()` class and they work well. However, when I try to access any method that uses mysql from a different class, I get an error (bottom of page for formatting reasons)

With the debugging tool I noticed that when using the `main()` class, the connection is created and works fine, but when I use the `time()` class, the connection always stays `null`, even though it uses the exact same connection code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_time);
    try {
        // LoginActivity.loginToken
        System.out.println(sqlGetBoolean("sometext"));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // ...
}

public static boolean sqlGetBoolean(String token) throws SQLException {
    ConnectionClass connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
    Connection connection = connectionClass.getConnection();
    String sqlGetBoolean = "SELECT `Checkas` FROM `workers` WHERE `Login Token`=\"" + token + "\";";
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sqlGetBoolean);
    boolean checkas = true;
    while (rs.next()) {
        checkas = rs.getBoolean("Checkas");
    }

    return checkas;
}


public class ConnectionClass {

    public Connection getConnection() {
        String dbName = "****";
        String userName = "****";
        String password = "****";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://****.com:3306/";

        try {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I expect a `print` in the console to be either `true` or `false`, however when using `Time()` class I get this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.supersaugykla, PID: 24290
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.supersaugykla/com.example.supersaugykla.Time}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.sql.Statement java.sql.Connection.createStatement()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.sql.Statement java.sql.Connection.createStatement()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.supersaugykla.Time.sqlGetBoolean(Time.java:227)
    at com.example.supersaugykla.Time.onCreate(Time.java:52)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24290 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

- One problem is not closing `connection`, `statement` and `rs`.
  This best can be solved with try-with-resources that closes the AutoCloseable variables,
  even on thrown exception or return.
- SQL should use *single quote* instead of double quote, which officially is for a column name.
- Use *prepared statements* which is type-safe, does escaping like single quote, backslash. And prevents hacking, *SQL injection*.

So:

```
public static boolean sqlGetBoolean(String token) throws SQLException {
    ConnectionClass connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
    String sqlGetBoolean = "SELECT `Checkas` FROM `workers` WHERE `Login Token`=?";
    try (Connection connection = connectionClass.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlGetBoolean)) {
        statement.setString(1, token); // First ? replaced with '+escaped(token)+'
        try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                return rs.getBoolean("Checkas");
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

Furthermore an exception seems to get swallowed. Better pass the exception of `getConnection`.

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    String dbName = "****";
    String userName = "****";
    String password= "****";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://****.com:3306/";
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName, userName, password);
}
```

Do a *clean build*, ensuring that everything gets recompiled.

Comment: I tried your solution but I still get the exact same error message.

Comment: I added an improved `getConnection` that caused the null. Now the exception probably is more informative.

Comment: After adding the SQLException, the app no longer crashes, however I still don't get my end result (true/false) and am greeted with this message:
    I/e.supersaugykl: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mysql.cj.MysqlType>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/sql/SQLType;

Comment: I hope someone else can shed hishers light on that. Try `rs.getObject(1)` first, and inspect that Object.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the problems that might be causing the issues

1. you're re-creating a connection every time, and that too on a mobile device? perhaps you should create a connection, and keep it open for some time.
2. make requests asynchronously (AsynchronousTask / AsyncTask pardon me I've forgotten what it's called), and not in the activity thread, that should solve your problem, mobile devices are not meant for reconnecting and sending remote requests in activity thread. main in an android is not an activity thread so your code is working in main but activity thread cannot do that. It's in-efficient and may be new versions wont even allow it.

you can use Thread class (async task is just for fetching data using http apparently)

```
public abstract class MyThread extends Thread {
    public abstract void onResponse( Response response );

    public void run() {
        // your mysql related code goes here
        // when response is received from mysql
        this.onResponse( response );
    }

    public void setQuery( String query ) {
        // 
    }
}

public myFunction() {
    MyThread thread = new MyThread() {
        public void onResponse( Response response ) {
            // do something with the response

        }
    };
    thread.setQuery( query );
    thread.start();

}
```

the code would look something like this for asynchronously fetching data through mysql

Comment: So for the 1st issue do you mean I should just establish when the app launches and just leave it there?
Also, for the 2nd one, I have little to no experience with AsyncTask and when I tried to search it up on google I'm very confused on how to use them, could you please elaborate on what I should do?
Very thankful for the help by the way.